# Кодировка при использовании curl

Tags: php, curl

Отправляю пост запрос на чужой сервер `curl`'ом. Необходимое действие на целевом сайте выполняется и печатается ответ сервера в формате `json`. Проблема в том что я получаю этот ответ в виде кракозябр

���`I�%&/m�{J�J��t��`$ؐ@�������iG#)�*��eVe]f@�흼��{����{����;�N'���?\fdl��J�ɞ!���?~|?"~�G��f]�=��=+����"��gO�6���r]�#j�����?yZM׋|�6'�?��g��}�� ?�?߹����?��?���>ȧ{۳��l7��ߛ���h��WM^����ý��F��y��R:�hog��m���雝�G{�v����4_��ʳٵ�������i����JǓ��_���6��-�6[N;���|�,�����G;�l�������uݾ�.<�����4���Xf%�>`�[�`

Как это можно исправить. Перебрал уже все возможные кодировки, пытался конвертировать, но безрезультатно. Заголовки ответа сервера:

```
HTTP/1.1 100 Continue

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Length: 2092
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Content-Encoding: gzip
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
Set-Cookie: .ASPXAUTH=fixcookie; path=/; expires=Tue, 02-Apr-2012 14:12:08 GMT; HttpOnly
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
X-Powered-By: ARR/2.5
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Sun, 06 Mar 2016 05:29:09 GMT
```

Comment: Возможно сервер неверно фрмирует кодировку? Или кодировка вашего терминала не соответствует выводимому тексту ?

Comment: Разобрался, данные просто прилетают сжатыми gzip. Помогла функция gzdecode()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно curl сказать чтобы он автоматически раскодировал ответ, если он сжат `gzip`.

```
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_ENCODING, '');
```

Возможно так будет более удобно.